# Get Order ID in Custom Module

Tags: orders

First i make the custom module to add custom button in Order View page and its successfully added. Now i want to get the Current Order ID at my Custom Module Page. Please guide me how can i get the Current Order ID.

Basically i want to take the current order id by using query string to my next page.

Please let me know how can i get the order id at my next page?

**code**

```
addbuttoninorder($event) { 
     Mage::log("adadadasd"); 
     $block = $event->getBlock(); 
     $url = "exportleftovers.co/leopardmagento/…;; 
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
    $block->addButton('change_status', array( 
      'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Leopard TN New'),      
      // 'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}','{$block->getUrl('modulename/path/')}')", 
      'onclick' => "window.open('".$url."')", 'class' => 'go' ));
  }
```

Comment: add your code too in question

Comment: public function addbuttoninorder($event)
 { Mage::log("adadadasd");
  $block = $event->getBlock();
  $url = "http://www.exportleftovers.co/leopardmagento/api_call_get_orders_magento.php?order_id=$order";
  
   if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
     $block->addButton('change_status', array(
     'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Leopard TN New'),

    //  'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('modulename/path/')}')",
   
     'onclick' => "window.open('".$url."')",

     'class'     => 'go'
    ));}

Answer (score 0):

if you have query string like : `www.DOMAIN.com/MODULENAME/CONTROLLER/ACTION/order_id/52`

then you can get `order_id` from query srting by `$this->getRequest()->getParam("order_id");`

**Update**: For `Observer.php`, you can use

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParams();
```

or

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams()
```

Comment: my query string is like $url = "http://www.exportleftovers.co/leopardmagento/api_call_get_orders_magento.php?order_id=$order";

Comment: then use `$_REQUEST["order_id"];`

Comment: no no i need the order id in current page  of module file like Observer.php

Comment: check answer updated

Comment: how can i write the code to get the order id? can you please let me know?

Comment: need more details, like , this function `addbuttoninorder($event) ` is in observer ? Why is it used ? From your description, I can just guess that , you want to get `order_id` param from some url.

Comment: Basically my requirement is add custom button in Order View Page in admin backend. So i google it and get some code to make a button. Now button is showing in the order view page. Now i want when i click on it my external URL link will be open and current order id will also available in the external page.

Comment: code: class Solsint_Cancelorder_Model_Observer {public function addbuttoninorder($event){ Mage::log("adadadasd"); $block =$event->getBlock();$order=Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParams();$url = "http://www.exportleftovers.co/leopardmagento/api_call_get_orders_magento.php?order_id=$order";if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {$message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure you want to Change Status?');
$block->addButton('change_status', array('label'=>Mage::helper('sales')->__('TN'), 'onclick' =>"window.open('".$url."')",'class' => 'go'));}}

Comment: Try to echo this `echo $event->getOrder()->getEntityId();` in this method. Let me know if you are getting some id

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getEntityId() on null in /home/exportl1/public_html/image/app/code/local/Solsint/Cancelorder/Model/Observer.php on line 44 code is: echo $event->getOrder()->getEntityId();